# How Do You Add MovieClips to Stage From Classes?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

Actionscript 3 classes are so confusing to me.

I have defined a variable `up_dpad` to `dpad_up`, where then I have attempted to add it to the stage by putting addChild(up_dpad) in the compiler function.

This is supposed to be simple code, but I cannot understand why it doesn't work, had it been on the timeline it would've worked just fine, and this is why I don't understand why people say to put code in classes rather than on the timeline, because from what I can tell it's so annoying.  Sorry for the rant, I'm just frustrated.

**Timeline**

```
new Test();
```

**Test.as Class**

```
    package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Test extends MovieClip
    {
        var up_dpad:MovieClip = new dpad_Up();


        public function Test()
        {
            addChild(up_dpad);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The code is fine. Did you export the item in the Library as dpad_Up class? Ah, BTW. On timeline it also should be addChild(new Test()) because you create it but never add it to display list.

Comment: Your actually amazing.  I had the movie clips exported, but my timeline code was incorrect. So thank you very much.